# How can I programmatically get the `recently visited sharepoint site` of current user in the tenant?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I would like to create an application (WebPart) that shows the recently visited SharePoint Site.
I have tried using MicrosoftGraph API and it gave me an empty value

Here is what I tried (Checked on MS Graph Explorer)

Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/insights/used

Response:"value": []

```
this.properties.graphClient.api("me/insights/used")
                          .version("beta")
                          .filter(`ResourceVisualization/Type eq 'Web'`)
                          .top(5)
                          .get((err, res: IRecentWebs) => {

           if (err) {
               return; 
           }

           if(res && res.value && res.value.length > 0) {
               this. _renderRecentSites(res.value);
           } else{
               alert('No site found');
           }
       });
```

and also tried to change the filter to

```
     ...
     .filter(`ResourceVisualization/containerType eq 'Site'`)
     ...
```

still got nothing.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported container types are listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/insights-resourcevisualization?view=graph-rest-beta

```
OneDriveBusiness
Site
Mail
DropBox
Box
GDrive
```

Web is not a supported container type. It is a resource visualization type. Site is a supported container type.

If you go to Graph Explorer you can see this working on our sample user account.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/insights/used?$filter=ResourceVisualization/containerType eq 'Site'&method=GET&version=beta&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com

If you sign into Graph Explorer and run the same query, you should see results here for any active usage inside of OneDrive for Business. Do you see that?

Comment: Yes, I see the active usage inside of my OneDrive for Business if I change containerType to OneDriveBusiness.

Comment: Was this the correct answer? If so do you mind marking this as answered please  @Izle